# Finding the coordinates of a point on a line closest to a given point

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I have a line from A to B and point C. I have the coordinates of A, B, and C, and I need to find the location of D which is the closest point on the line to C:

[image]

Keep in mind that A, B, and C could be any point in space. I have tried many attempts and failed.

Comment: What do you mean by "with inaccuracy" in your title? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Perhaps you can consider a "moving" point $D(t)$ along the line AB. The angle between $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{CD(t)}$ must now be 90 degrees. From this relation you should be able to solve for $t$.

Comment: well if I can get the area I can probably get the length between D and C which would allow me to use the cosine rule to get the answer

Comment: well the path a to b is a bus path and the gps is a bit off the line which is c

Comment: The topic of this should be geometry, rather than trigonometry. There aren't any angles required. And the title should probably read something along the lines of "How can I find the point on a line closest to a given point?"
The current title is quite unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is the perpendicular projection of $\vec{C}$ on the line through $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$. To learn more try this wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection

We can use the dot product to compute this vector projection, keeping in mind that the vectors aren't normalized when we plug this vector into the formula $\frac{a\cdot b}{b\cdot b}b$ we get:

$$\vec{D}-\vec{A} = \frac{(\vec{B}-\vec{A})\cdot(\vec{C}-\vec{A})}{(\vec{B}-\vec{A})\cdot(\vec{B}-\vec{A})} (\vec{B}-\vec{A}).$$

If you bring $\vec{A}$ over to the other side of the equation, you get a formula for $\vec{D}$ in terms of $\vec{A}, \vec{B}$ and $\vec{C}$.

EDIT:

For example If we take $\vec{A} = (0, 0)$, $\vec{B} = (1, 1)$ and $\vec{C} = (1, 0)$.

In this case $\vec{B} - \vec{A} = (1, 1) - (0, 0) = (1, 1)$.

The squared norm of this vector is $(\vec{B}-\vec{A})\cdot (\vec{B}-\vec{A}) = (1, 1) \cdot (1, 1) = 1.1+1.1 = 2$

The other vector is $\vec{C}-\vec{A} = (1, 0) - (0, 0) = (1, 0)$.

The innerproduct of these vectors is $(\vec{B}-\vec{A})\cdot (\vec{C}-\vec{A}) = (1, 1)\cdot(1, 0) = 1.1 + 1.0 = 1$.

The quotient of these two innerproducts is $\frac{(\vec{B}-\vec{A})\cdot(\vec{C}-\vec{A})}{(\vec{B}-\vec{A})\cdot(\vec{B}-\vec{A})} = \frac{1}{2}.$

To get the vector $\vec{D}-\vec{A}$ we need to multiply this fraction by $\vec{B}-\vec{A}$. This means the following calculation $\frac{(\vec{B}-\vec{A})\cdot(\vec{C}-\vec{A})}{(\vec{B}-\vec{A})\cdot(\vec{B}-\vec{A})} (\vec{B}-\vec{A}) = \frac{1}{2} (\vec{B}-\vec{A}) = \frac{1}{2}(1, 1) = (.5, .5)$.

Finally we computed the vector $\vec{D}-\vec{A}$, to get the exact position of $\vec{D}$ we add $\vec{A}$. In other words $\vec{D} = (.5, .5) + \vec{A} = (.5, .5) + (0, 0) = (.5, .5)$.

As expected the point $\vec{D}$ lies at coordinates $(.5, .5)$.

Comment: $\vec{D} - \vec{A}$ is a difference of two vectors if you add $\vec{A}$ to both sides of the equation you get $\vec{D} = \frac{(\vec{B}-\vec{A})\cdot(\vec{C}-\vec{A})}{(\vec{B}-\vec{A})\cdot(\vec{B}-\vec{A})} (\vec{B}-\vec{A}) + \vec{A}$.

Comment: I'm trying to program it and I tried this where a is at 0,0 b 1,1 and c 1,0 the result I want to get is 0.5 I tried to use that formula but got  $\approx$ 7

Comment: I need a scale from 0 to 1 so I need A-D / A-B I'm not that good at trigonometry and am trying to work a lot of it out

Comment: I hope the example clarifies the formula. This should help you find the location of $\vec{D}$ and answer the question.